# How to deepcopy shelve objects in Python

Tags: python, copy, deep-copy, shelve

Is it possible to deepcopy a shelve object in Python? When I try to deepcopy it, I get the following error:

```
import shelve,copy
input = shelve.open("test.dict", writeback=True)
input.update({"key1": 1, "key2": 2})
newinput = copy.deepcopy(input)
>> object.__new__(DB) is not safe, use DB.__new__()
```

Does it mean shelves are not-copyable?

Edit: Maybe it might be better if I elaborate my problem more: I am keeping a large dictionary as a shelve object, and I want to save the whole shelve object (= all key, val pairs I generated so far) to a seperate file while I keep adding new items to the original dict.

Probably I could first sync the shelve and copy the shelve file on disk explicitly, however I don't like that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could obtain a shallow copy by `dict(input)` and `deepcopy` that. Then maybe create another shelve on a new file and populate it via the `update` method.

```
newinput = shelve.open("newtest.dict")
newinput.update(copy.deepcopy(dict(input)))
```

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think they are copiable (unless you monkey patch the class or convert into a dict). Here's why :

`copy.copy()` and `copy.deepcopy()` call the `__copy__()` and `__deepcopy__()` methods for the instances which does not depend on a "standard" type (which are `atomic`, `list`, `tuple`  and `instance methods` ). If the class does not have those attributes, it falls back to `__reduce_ex__` and `__reduce__` . (see `copy.py` in your sources)

Unfortunately, the shelve object `Shelf` is based on `UserDict.DictMixin` which does not define `copy()` (and neither does `Shelf`) :

> **class DictMixin:**
>
> ```
> # Mixin defining all dictionary methods for classes that already have
> # a minimum dictionary interface including getitem, setitem, delitem,
> # and keys. Without knowledge of the subclass constructor, the mixin
> # does not define __init__() or copy().  In addition to the four base
> # methods, progressively more efficiency comes with defining
> # __contains__(), __iter__(), and iteritems().
> ```

It may be a good idea to submit an issue to the shelve module bug tracker.

Comment: i was wondering how I can check whether an object is copyable or not, thanks for the nice explanation!